# How to fix redis session in yii2 it does log in my users

Tags: redis, yii2, yii-extensions

I install redis on my Yii2 application, i am using redis session, is working ofline perfectly but when try to login as user online after add the user details it will bring blank page, not until i refresh more than two or three time before it will login, and if i remove redis session is working perfectly

//my web config

```
'class'=>'app\components\DateFormat',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        ],
        'redis' => [
            'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
            //'connectionTimeout'=>null,

        ],
        'session' => [

           'class' => 'yii\redis\Session',

            'timeout'=>600,


        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
```

// my logaction in controller

```
 public function actionLogin()
    {


        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
      //  $login = new \app\models\LoginDetails();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            //$log = \app\models\User::find()->where(['user_login_id' => $_POST['LoginForm']['username'], 'is_block' => 0])->one();
            /*if (empty($log)) {
                \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('loginError', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i><b> Incorrect username or password. !</b>');
                return $this->render('login', ['model' => $model]);
            }*/

          //  $login->login_user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id;
           $loginuser = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_id;

            $user_type = Yii::$app->user->identity->user_type;


            $currentSes = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("Select aca.activesessions_id, aca.activesemester_id,ses.batch_name from activeacademic aca
join sessions ses on ses.batch_id= aca.activesessions_id join semester sem on sem.semester_id=aca.activesemester_id
where programme_id=:prg AND aca.activestatus=1", [':prg' => Yii::$app->user->identity->program_id])->queryOne();
            //  print_r($currentSes);die();
            if (!empty($currentSes)) {
              //  $ses = $currentSes['activesessions_id'];
               // $sem = $currentSes['activesemester_id'];
                Yii::$app->session->set('active_ses',  $currentSes['activesessions_id']);
                Yii::$app->session->set('active_sem',  $currentSes['activesemester_id']);
                /* $active_ses_name = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("Select batch_name from sessions where batch_id=:id",
                     [':id' => $ses])->queryOne()['batch_name']; */
                Yii::$app->session->set('active_ses_name', $currentSes['batch_name']);

            }
            if ( $user_type == 'S') {


               $studlogin = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("Select stu_master_id from stu_master where stu_master_user_id=:sd",[':sd'=>$loginuser])->queryOne();//StuMaster::find()->andWhere(['stu_master_user_id' => $loginuser])->one();
                if(!empty($studlogin))
                    \Yii::$app->session->set('stu_id', $studlogin['stu_master_id']);
                \Yii::$app->session->set('student_data',$studlogin);


            } else if ( $user_type == 'E') {

                $emplogin = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("select emp_master_id, emp_master_academic_department_id from emp_master where emp_master_user_id=:em",[':em'=>$loginuser])->queryOne();//EmpMaster::find()->andWhere(['emp_master_user_id' => $loginuser])->one();
                if(!empty($emplogin)){
                \Yii::$app->session->set('emp_id', $emplogin['emp_master_id']);
                \Yii::$app->session->set('emp_dept_id', $emplogin['emp_master_academic_department_id']);}
            } else if ($user_type == 'A') {
                \Yii::$app->session->set('admin_user', $loginuser);
            } else {
                if (isset(Yii::$app->user->id))
                    Yii::$app->user->logout();
                \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('loginError', '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i><b> These Login credentials are Blocked/Deactive by Admin</b>');
                return $this->render('login', ['model' => $model,]);
            }
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->insert('login_details',['login_user_id'=>$loginuser,'login_status'=>1,'login_at'=>date('Y-m-d h:i:s'),'user_ip_address'=> $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']])->execute();
           return $this->goBack();


        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

//error  log

```
 PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
session_regenerate_id(): Failed to create(read) session ID: user (path: )
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in error log? Blank page usually means fatal error.

Comment: Please How can i find log, i cant find any log

Comment: What i mean is that it already online and is working perfectly ofline, if i first login it render blank if i refresh two or three time is will log in

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add configurations of redis in session section, try this:

```
    'session' => [
       'class' => 'yii\redis\Session',
       'redis' => 'redis'
       'timeout'=>600,
    ],
```

or this:

```
    'session' => [
       'class' => 'yii\redis\Session',
       'redis' => [
            'class' => 'yii\redis\Connection',
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
            'database' => 0,
       ]
       'timeout'=>600,
    ],
```

in second example you can change your store configurations, for example virtual database:

```
'database' => 2
```

or other configurations.